References are getting out of order
I am stuck with quite a complex problem with my springer nature template. The references are out of order as shown below:

Below the latex code:
% This is samplepaper.tex, a sample chapter demonstrating the
% LLNCS macro package for Springer Computer Science proceedings;
% Version 2.21 of 2022/01/12
%
% \documentclass[runningheads]{llncs}
\documentclass[runningheads, orivec]{llncs}  % orivec is needed to display vector with arrow on top
%
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
% T1 fonts will be used to generate the final print and online PDFs,
% so please use T1 fonts in your manuscript whenever possible.
% Other font encondings may result in incorrect characters.
%
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{braket}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{svg}
\usepackage{physics}  % This package resolved the error due to \split
\usepackage[font=small,labelfont=bf]{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{soul}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{placeins}  % control figure float
% Used for displaying a sample figure. If possible, figure files should
% be included in EPS format.
%
% If you use the hyperref package, please uncomment the following two lines
% to display URLs in blue roman font according to Springer's eBook style:
%\usepackage{color}
%\renewcommand\UrlFont{\color{blue}\rmfamily}
%\urlstyle{rm}
%
\begin{document}
%
\title{Title}
%
%\titlerunning{Abbreviated paper title}
% If the paper title is too long for the running head, you can set
% an abbreviated paper title here
%
\author{Author1 \and
Author2}
% Third Author\inst{3}\orcidID{2222--3333-4444-5555}} \and
%
\institute{University,USA\\\email{\{manynu\}@unv.com}}
%
\maketitle              % typeset the header of the contribution
%
\begin{abstract}
\end{abstract}
\section{Introduction}\label{sec:1}
\vspace{-1em}
The references are not comimg in order\cite{cite1}. Please help \cite{cite2, cite3, cite4}.



\section{Conclusion and Future Work}\label{sec:6}

\begin{credits}
\subsubsection{\ackname}
This research good.
\end{credits}
\bibliographystyle{splncs04}
\bibliography{refs}
\end{document}

Really not sure how to correct this issue.
Thank you for great help.

References in order of appearance might be a choice for short articles, but not for lecture notes, where browsing the references is common. My personal opinion is that references in order of appearance are a relic of the past and should be banned altogether in any scientific field.

You are mentioning "Springer Nature template" but your first line is
\documentclass[runningheads, orivec]{llncs}

which is not this template. You are actually using the Springer Lecture Notes in Computer Science document class (https://ctan.org/pkg/llncs). The corresponding bibliography style that you are using, sorts references by author surname, not by order of appearance; therefore, the result you are getting is probably correct (you do not provide your list of references).
You can get the "Springer Nature template", if this is what you actually want, from https://www.springernature.com/gp/authors/campaigns/latex-author-support.

Thank you @nplatis for response. The paper I am preparing is for conference proceedings. The link given by conference to download the template is : https://www.springer.com/gp/computer-science/lncs/conference-proceedings-guidelines

https://resource-cms.springernature.com/springer-cms/rest/v1/content/19242230/data/v13  This is the instructions given

Yes, the current template is arranging everything alphabatically but it looks kind of odd in the paper so I want to correct it @nplatis.

If the conference provides this template, they do it to ensure consistent look for all the papers; therfore, you should not try to alter it in any way. Besides, they will probably format the final papers themselves for the proceedings, using your sources.

Thank you for response @nplatis. Is there some way to override this. These editors generally send back the paper to get the format corrected and give unncessary stress.

I don't really understand your question. As I said, they will ensure consistency for the volume of proceedings. Even if you change the order of references, they will change it back to what they want.

Thank you @nplatis for the help. I got your point.
